# Apache Storm (0.9)- Different Topology name but same Code

Tags: apache-storm

I am deploying same Storm code with topology Name reading different topic name .

I am  seeing same message getting processed by both topologies .

For e.g:-
Topic1 - Storm Topology 1 (Storm Code)
Topic2 - Storm Topology 2 (Storm Code)

So if we send one message on Topic 1 -> Message is getting processed by both Storm Topology 1 and Storm Topology 2.

Ideally, it shouldn't

Can any one help me with that ?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're reading from Kafka. Could you post your setup code (the part that initializes the KafkaSpout)?

Comment: It working now since we are connecting to different topics with different topology name but same code base.